# Running Tor on lxc-based virtual infrastructure

Tags: relays, debian

I tried to set up a Tor relay node on my server running Debian squeeze with Linux containers for better maintainability. Installing from main repository and Tor repository failed. In debug.log there is only one error message:

```
[err] /dev/null can't be opened. Exiting.
```

I have full access to /dev/null in the container, for example

```
dd if=/home of=/dev/null
```

works proper.

Config of the lxc container is with option

```
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:3 rwm
```

So, does anybody got an idea whats wrong there?

Comment: Please don't cross-post.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i got it... the permissions inside the LXC is different to the hosts permisssons.

While the host has 0666 on /dev/null, the container has read-only access. It is a bit strange because the lxc config file has something like

```
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 1:3 rwm
```

for /dev/null.